# How would I make an indent that runs on all sides of the object?

Tags: modeling, extrude

[image]

I'm trying to make an old PC monitor and there is a seam that runs all around. I tried Extruding inwards but since it runs on all sides it just goes in one direction. Sorry.. still learning Blender. What should I do?

[image]

Also should I be using inset and extrude for the smaller heat vents? Or is there a better way to go about it?

Comment: your problem is not clear, you need to extrude and scale down, constrain your scale on Z ans X axis with shift Y. For heat vents create a lot of additional loops and extrude inwards.

Comment: sorry... if i wasnt clear.. but the suggestion worked .. i didnt think about scaling down the extruded portion... thanks a ton....

Comment: In "real life" it is a separate part of the monitor, that can be unscrewed (screw hole in image above) and detached. Could make model separate parts too.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply *Inset* the faces

1. Select your loop
2. Inset it by 0, set depth as desired
3. Check *Offset Even*

[image]

Comment: Perfect... Thanks so much

Comment: Hey! A new 1-tool way! (to me, I mean ..I've always done it in 2 steps, using Alt-E)

Comment: Hey! Extrude along normals is even more elegant :). Thanks.